# Magic methods don't work inside ArrayObjects?

Tags: php, magic-methods, arrayobject

I ran accross a problem with my code that I could not explain. The only thing I can think of is that magic methods just don't work inside of ArrayObjects. For instance, given the following class:

```
class foo extends ArrayObject {

    public $bar = '@@@';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(array(), ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
    }

    public function __get($prop) {
        return '@@@';
    }
}
```

The following lines give me an error "Notice: Undefined index: test ..."

```
$foo = new foo();
echo $foo->test;
```

Yet these lines work fine:

```
$foo = new foo();
echo $foo->bar;
```

Am I crazy or is this a known issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "magic" function you're looking for is called [`offsetGet`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.offsetget.php), not `__get`:

```
class foo extends ArrayObject {

    public $bar = '@@@';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(array(), ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
    }

    public function offsetGet($prop)
    {
        if (!parent::offsetExists($prop))
            return '@@@';
        return parent::offsetGet($prop);
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
echo $foo->test; # @@@
```

I don't know it for sure, but `__get` is not available as you're extending from an internal class that is somehow blocking it.

Comment: very interesting. so i have to overwrite part of the ArrayAccess interface instead of using normal magic methods for ArrayObjects. i will have to try this out. makes me think that I should just implement an ArrayAccess interface instead of extending the ArrayObject though.

Comment: The benefit of extending from ArrayObject normally is that you don't need to type that much while already having all you need - well sort of :)